# И снова о Самаре и Самарии

Tags: топонимика

Прочитала предыдущий вопрос о самаритянах и захотелось задать свой. Меня всегда интересовало: название города Самара связано с библейской Самарией или просто созвучно ей?
Спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Город Самара расположен на левом возвышенном берегу Волги напротив Самарской Луки (излучины Волги), при впадении в неё реки Самары (отсюда название города). Самара была основана по указу царя Фёдора в 1586 году как сторожевая крепость Самарский городок.

Корни названия реки Самары следует искать в развитии языков как местных народов, так и в языках восточной группы. Слово САМ встречается не только в именах собственных  (Самарканд,  Самара,  Самария), но и в соответствующих этим местам климатических явлениях. К примеру, у арабов сухой жаркий ветер пустынь - самум, шамсином (хамсином) у египтян также называется жаркий ветер, в Сирии словом "шам" обозначают пустыню.

Интересно также значение корня  АР.  Эта форма также входит в словарь народов Востока, Средней Азии и Европы со значением "река". В частности, у венгров, чьи предки до IX века кочевали за Волгой, слово "ар" и по сию пору означает "поток", "река". Из всего этого следует, что семантика топонима Самар (или в более позднем варианте Самара) означает "степная река".